# Inductive step in mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the purpose of replacing P(n) with P(k) during the inductive step? Isn't n and k representing the same thing? Why can't I just assume that if P(n) is true, then P(n+1) is true?

Comment: 1. Convenience, 2. Yes, 3. You can.

Comment: For ordinary induction you only assume $P(n)$ for the induction step, but for *strong* induction you assume $P(k)$ for all $k<n$. So this is the reason for replacing $P(n)$ then by $P(k)$. By the way, please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You can't "just assume that if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is true" - you have to prove it.

Comment: When teaching the principle of induction it is often easier to explain things by using k and then to work with cases k=n and k=n+1. Otherwise people get confused when substituting n+1 into n and write nonsense like n=n+1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple induction proof look something like this:

- **Let $P(n)$ denote** the proposition $n^2>7n+1.$

  ...

  Take an arbitrary integer greater than $7,$ denote it by $k,$ and **suppose that $P(k)$ is true.**

  ...

  Hence, by induction, for each integer greater than **$7,\;P(n)$ is true.**

While your suggestion is not technically wrong (since the variable $k$ is bound within the middle section of the above presentation), it's more systematic, and friendlier to the reader, to use a different variable, like $k,$ instead of $n,$ within the proof.

Besides, by giving $k$ the same name as $n$ (i.e., calling both $n$), doesn't it sound circular that we seem to be proving $P(n)$ by supposing $P(n)\;?$